# Centos 7, php 5.4, httpd 2.4, oci8 - undefined symbol: php_checkuid in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, oci8

So I have my entire application stack running on Centos 6 and am taking a crack at re-building everything with Centos 7. I've built a Centos 7 VM and have most things working. For whatever reason, I can't seem to get OCI working with the combination of packages I have installed.

Here is my stack:
Centos 7.3 (3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64)
php 5.4
httpd 2.4
oci8 (2.0.7).

When I start up apache, I get the following errors:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so: undefined symbol: php_checkuid in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 11 18:20:02.228573 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8979] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations

I've read over and over how to install oci8, and followed them (I've done this before without issues on RH 6), restarted httpd and still it doesn't work.

I have an oracle client installed (not instant client).

Here are the instructions I've used to install oci8:

```
# phpize

Set Oracle Home
# ./configure --with-oci8=shared,$ORACLE_HOME
# make
# make install


The above creates the oci8.so in the modules subdirectory. It also copies it to /usr/lib64/php/modules

vi /etc/php.ini
At bottom, put:
[OCI8]
extension=oci8.so

Restart apache
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

-Jim

Comment: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50486

Comment: I read that article before and didn't really understand it. Everything I've done is installed with yum. Anyway, I did find this:pecl install oci8-2.0.12, which worked for me. I can't believe how long I've searched and found it today (of course after I posted the above message). Debated posting this question to start with. Anyway, thanks for re-pointing me to that url.

Comment: My bad, I thought by "rebuilding everything" you meant recompiling. Sorry, I could have been more helpful, CentOS is a bit more touchy than other distros. Glad you solved your problem with pecl.